# How to extract data from a raw HTML file?

Tags: php, html, parsing, html-content-extraction

Is there a way to extract desired data from a raw html which has been written unsemantically with no `IDs` and `classes`? I mean, suppose there is a saved html file of a webpage (profile) and I want to extract the data like (say) 'hobbies'. Is it possible to do this using PHP?

Comment: You can use regular expressions in PHP for this purpose. PHP is not a NLP specific language, but you can of course extract information from the dcouments as in other general purpose languages.

Comment: regular expressions aren't suitable for HTML I'm afraid. It's not a regular language.

Comment: Regular expressions work fine. you don't need to do brace matching. I've spidered millions of pages just using regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not saying they won't work at all, but reliable HTML parsing is beyond the capabilities of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)! I kid, I kid. If you know the state of the same page, and the format is guaranteed to remain similar enough, then you can try writing a manual parser. Alternatively, there are a lot of libraries out there that will parse html for. I'm not familiar enough with PHP to recommend one, but I'm sure some Googleing could take you a long way. I've had luck with John Resig's [pure javascript HTML parser](http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/) before.

At the end of the day, if you need semantic information from an html page that isn't constructed semantically, you're probably doomed programmatically and your best bet may be a [mechanical turk](https://www.mturk.com/mturk/welcome).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for a PHP DOM Parser, such as [this one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/). It'll probably be a bit tricky to pull out the data you need if the HTML is truly devoid of semantic structure, but a DOM parser is the place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the technique is called [web scraping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping). You could use the DOM if its valid html. If the page is dynamically generated the generator would have used some structure, and from my experience you can always isolate elements of interest.

If DOM does not work for you, you can just use regular expressions (thats what I always used to do when writing web-spiders). Regular expressions are more effective and quicker that writing scraping logic against a DOM heirarchy. So you need to open a few of the profile pages and analyze the static structure. Then just write a regular expression to isolate the fields of interest.

Answer (score 0):

There's two approaches to take with PHP.  The first is to clean your document up using [the tidy extension](http://php.net/tidy) so it's valid XHTML, and therefore well-formed XML, and therefore can be parsed using XML tools.

The second is to use the PHP release of [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) parser, which attempts to implement the HTML5 research into current browser parsing routines.  If it displays in a browser, html5lib can parse it.

Using either approach you'll end up with a DOM object you can query using xpath expressions.  Since your theoretical documents lack semantic structure, you'll want toook at the document parts from a  "the 5th span inside the 3rd p" mindset.

More information [here](http://alanstorm.com/parsing_html_with_php) (self-link warning).