# Get all media (images, video...) from a multiple URLs using PHP

Tags: php, web-scraping, reddit

Hi I'm trying to write a PHP script that download all images and videos from a subreddit and store them locally.

My plan is to get all the links from a URL then process to decide whether it's an image or video then download it.

If someone can guide me or give me an idea on how to proceed that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to curl download the link to website, so you get the html version of it, than take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423272/how-to-extract-links-and-titles-from-a-html-page) topic. Having this, you can extract all needed tags, for example "img" tags and their href.

Than just load them into array, and iterate curl to download them and store them locally.

Another approach would be to download html and load all links based on  filter (ex. beggining on "\"http://" and ending with quote (also make another filter for single quote if there are singe quotes in the html).
Than just iterate all of links and whitelist them based on extension, if that's file what you are intrested in. Than curl download and store them.

EDIT:
I forgot - also do not forget to fix links in the .html and .css and .js (and probably more) files. Also just offtopic sidenote, watch out for images with php in them.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help !

Comment: no problem.
Have fun with project. It seems like a lotta fun in your project ;)