# Loading only part of site into dom via jquery

Tags: jquery, web, load

I currently attempt loading a crosssite into the current dom via

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript">
{
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bitbucketissue").load("https://bitbucket.org/alceawisteria/ostr/issues?status=new&status=open");
});
}
</script>
    <div class="formClass">
        <div id="bitbucketissue">
        </div>
```

However I only need the "central" 'issue portion' of the page.

Is there a way to cut that "out" ?

(PS: iframes don't work, bitbucket bars em. And Xframes load forever...)

Load site via jquery into current dom.

Site loads, but I need only the center part of it ...

Applied solution as suggested by David (https://stackoverflow.com/users/328193/david):

https://codepen.io/ryedai1/pen/RwBGbNb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery `load()` function](https://api.jquery.com/load/) allows you to also specify a selector.  The example from the documentation is:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html #container" );
```

What this does is specifically select `#container` in the response DOM and discard the rest.  Note of course that the entire response is still received, the rest of the content is just discarded client-side.

So whatever selector you would use in the resulting DOM from your response, simply append that to your URL:

```
$("#bitbucketissue").load("https://bitbucket.org/alceawisteria/ostr/issues?status=new&status=open #someSelector");
```

Comment: And what selector for the #container would that be in the examplesite ? (To be able to answer this question and get an example)

Comment: @Rye: That's really up to you.  What is the exact HTML you're receiving?  What part of that HTML are you targeting?  Basically, just as with any selector for JavaScript/CSS, when you debug what is the exact element you are trying to select?

Comment: <section id="issues-list" data-module="issues/views/issues-screen"> would be the starting delimiter I'm fairly certain, but can that suffice ?

Comment: @Rye: Well, if the element you're targeting has `id="issues-list"`, then the selector would/should be `#issues-list`.